# Durandal: how to properly make ajax requests in shell activate function

Tags: jquery, durandal

When my SPA initializes it has to make some ajax calls that need to run before any views get loaded. I have placed these in the activate function of shell.js. In other views I return these calls from the activate function and all works fine. But in the shell I should return from the router.activate call. How to to return the proper view and assure that those ajax calls are made? What I see is the data doesn't always load.

```
 activate: function () {

            var query =
           $.when(
                    datacontext.getCurrentUser(),
                    datacontext.getGroupsAuthorized(),
                    datacontext.getTeams(),
                    datacontext.getRoles(),
                    datacontext.checkPermissions('views.shell')
                    )
            .then(function (s0, s1, s2,s3, s4) {    
                /* code excluded */        
            },
            function (f0, f1, f2) {
               /* code excluded */

            }).always( function() {
                /* code excluded */                   
            });

            return router.activate('welcome');

    },
```

all of the datacontext calls look something like this:

```
getCurrentUser = function () {          
       return $.ajax({
           url: 'api/currentuser/',
           type: 'GET'
       });
   },
```

Comment: although you can make many ajax requests from the client to the server at the same time, I think its bad from a scalability front. Session on the server can be accessed by one request at a time, remaining requests coming in are queued. When multiple users try to launch this view at the same time your server will be overloaded with many queued up requests there by limiting scalability. Another thing to keep in mind will be that if you have authortizing/authenticating code around these requests the each request will go through that again and again increasing duplication on code being executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to return a promise so that Durandal knows when it's allowed to continue composing.
Something along the line should do the trick.

```
activate: function () {

   return  $.when(
                datacontext.getCurrentUser(),
                datacontext.getGroupsAuthorized(),
                datacontext.getTeams(),
                datacontext.getRoles(),
                datacontext.checkPermissions('views.shell')
                )
        .then(function (s0, s1, s2,s3, s4) {    
            /* code excluded */        
            return router.activate('welcome');

        }
},
```

`function` and `always` needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough just to put the router.activate('welcome') snippet as another promise in the when clause?

```
activate: function () {    

       var query =
           $.when(
                    datacontext.getCurrentUser(),
                    datacontext.getGroupsAuthorized(),
                    datacontext.getTeams(),
                    datacontext.getRoles(),
                    datacontext.checkPermissions('views.shell'),
                    router.activate('welcome');
                    )
            .then(function (s0, s1, s2,s3, s4, s5) {    
                /* code excluded */        
            },
            function (f0, f1, f2) {
               /* code excluded */

            }).always( function() {
                /* code excluded */                   
            });

            return query;

    },
```